# bash script to find latest logfile

Tags: bash, wildcard-expansion

I want to find the latest logfile (.log extension) in a directory using a bash script.

At first my simple attempt worked ok

```
filename=`ls -t -c1 | head -1`
```

But when I admit that files other than logfiles could be found, this doesn't work because of wildcard expansion

```
filename=`ls -t -c1 *.log | head -1`
```

So I believe I have to read the ls command into an array or file, then process from there.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work because of wildcard expansion"?  It works for me.

Comment: You know, you're right, the example does work.  In simplifying my script into an example, something got lost.  I'll look more closely at the symptom I'm having and report tomorrow.  Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to work fine ....

```
 Kaizen ~/so_test $ ls -lt -c1 z*
-rw-r--r-- 1 Nitin None 318 Jun  5 21:59 ztestfile1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 Nitin None 398 Jun  5 21:41 zawk1.sh
```

alternatively you  could try your hand with find ....

```
 Kaizen ~/so_test $ find . -mtime 0 -a -mtime -1 -iname "z*" | xargs ls -ltr | sort -k9 -r
 -rw-r--r-- 1 Nitin None 318 Jun  5 21:59 ./ztestfile1
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 Nitin None 398 Jun  5 21:41 ./zawk1.sh
```

but this would need a bit of twik to suit your exact need.

Comment: After testing some more, I do *not* have a problem.  Sorry for the false alarm, but thanks for the advice....Lyle